# ConfirmDialog not working

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm trying to create a register window when i click a button from my "main" JFrame window.
For some reason `showConfirmDialog` won't take `OK_CANCEL_OPTION` as an argument. The RegTemplate is a JPanel with the stuff i want in my register window.

The strange thing is that I watch some example code that im 100% sure works and I have checked mine against this one but I can't find any real difference. The Marathon class is my "main" program window by the way.

Please tell my whats wrong here, I hope this code is enough.

```
class createListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave){
    RegTemplate reg = new RegTemplate();
    int choice = showConfirmDialog(Marathon.this, reg, "New participant", OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (choice != OK_OPTION)
            return;
    DO SOMETHING IF OK IS CLICKED
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your class extends from `JOptionPane` then `OK_CANCEL_OPTION` is an unknown identifier and your code won't compile. It should be [`JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#OK_CANCEL_OPTION) instead which is a public constant defined in `JOptionPane` class.

Try this:

```
int choice = showConfirmDialog(Marathon.this, reg, "New participant", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    if (choice != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){ ... }
```

Also you should take a look to [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) article.

---

#### Edit

I bring this up from the comments because it might be useful:

> I added a static import of JOptionPane.*; I made it static since i
>   will reuse it in several different popup windows, from what I
>   understand this might be an ok solution.

I think it is a unusual but very valid solution indeed, as stated in this article: [Static Imports](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Comment: Worked perfect, I added a static import of JOptionPane.*;
I made it static since i will reuse it in several different popup windows, from what I understand this might be an ok solution.

Comment: It's a not common but very valid solution indeed, as stated in [Static Import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) article. Glad it be helpful :) @user2225454